# ActiveRecord Rollback skips the model level errors in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord, transactions

Here is a code from controller action(Rails 3.2), User is the parent and having has_many association with Poster and Card. If the user object fails to save, I want to revert all queries executed.

Currently `@user.update_attributes!` gives a ActiveRecord exception for any error and Rollback occurs.

Along with rollback, I want the errors from other objects(child dependencies) also to be sent as response which is being missed as code will never enter else part on exception.

```
def update
  @user = User.includes(:posters).includes(:cards).find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
          ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            @user.cache_background_data
            @user.disable_messages
            @user.selected_tgs = params["up"] && params["up"]["s_tgs"]
            if @user.valid? && @user.update_attributes!(ng_user_params)
              render :json => Oj.dump(user_as_json(@user), mode: :compat)
            else
              render :json => Oj.dump({:errors => @user.errors}, mode: :compat)
            end
          end
      end
   end 
end
```

I tried handling this using the below code with rescue, in this flow the Rollback is not triggered. Can Rollback be handled forcefully(`raise ActiveRecord::Rollback`) and all custom ActiveRecord error messages appended in the response?

```
 rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError => e
   ng_collect_errors
   render :json => Oj.dump({:errors => @user.errors}, mode: :compat)
```

Currently with multiple options tried, there has been no help since Rollback can't be skipped.

Comment: You're defining `@users` but using `@user` further - is it a typo?

Comment: yes, it was typo, fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to raise rollback manually

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @user.cache_background_data
  @user.disable_messages
  @user.selected_tgs = params["up"] && params["up"]["s_tgs"]
  if @user.valid? && @user.update(ng_user_params)
    render :json => Oj.dump(user_as_json(@user), mode: :compat)
  else
    render :json => Oj.dump({:errors => @user.errors}, mode: :compat)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't help, i don't see Rollback fired in logs with invalid data entered.